# Django context processor to show images

Tags: django, django-templates

How to can add caption to each image in my `images_people` list?

This context_processor can be improved in the level practices sense?

I want show random images in my webpage, then I made a context processor

Context:

(previously added in my `context_processors` settings ...):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from random import choice

images_people = ['https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ihost-project/assets/img/bolivia2.jpg','2',
          'https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ihost-project/assets/img/bolivia3.jpg',
          'https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ihost-project/assets/img/bolivia4.jpg',
          'https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ihost-project/assets/img/bolivia-children.jpg',
          'https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ihost-project/assets/img/ElZocalo.jpg',
          'https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ihost-project/assets/img/israel.jpg',
          ]

def images(request):
    return {'images': choice(images_people)}
```

In my template I am invoking this context_processor:

```
<div class="portrait">
    <div class="img-cont" style="background: url('{{ images  }}') no-repeat center; background-size:cover;">
    </div>
         # Add caption to image
         <!-- <span></span> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the list in your context processor to be a list of 2-tuples of (url, caption).

```
images_people = [
    ('https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ihost-project/assets/img/bolivia2.jpg', 'Caption 1'), 
    ('https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ihost-project/assets/img/bolivia3.jpg', 'Caption 2),
    ...
]

def images(request):
    # n.b changed from `images` to `image` since it's a single image
    return {'image': choice(images_people)}
```

Then in your template, `{{ images.0 }}` will be the URL, and `{{ images.1 }}` will be the caption.

If you don't like accessing the tuple by index, you could look at [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or create a class.